# XAML DependencyProperty object notify parent on new instance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have DependecyProperty (named `Block`) on a XAML UserControl (named `BlockPresenter`) which expects a data type of `IBlock`. This `IBlock` intefae has a `Visual GetControl()` method - amongst other things - which returns an element of some kind to allow the user to edit the values for that specific block. The `BlockPresenter` provides a way of choosing which block to use (e.g. BlockA, BlockB, etc.) and also shows the `GetControl` return valued for the block itself.

There are models which contain one or more `IBlock` properties under varying different names. Each of these models has their own user control which has the model as it's DataContext. In the XAML for the model's control, I have lines such as `<controls:BlockPresenter Block="{Binding Foo}" />` to show the control and allow the user to change the block type or the properties for their chosen block.

When the user changes block type from the dropdown in BlockPresenter, a new instance of the selected block is created and set as the Block DependencyProperty and the presenter calls `GetControl` for the new Block. This is fine, however the problem is that this does not send the new value up to the model.

**BlockPresenter.xaml**

```xml
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#F00">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="BlockSelection" SelectedValuePath="BlockType" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectionChanged="BlockSelection_SelectionChanged" />
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" Margin="0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

**BlockPresenter.xaml.cs**

```cs
public BlockPresenter() {
    InitializeComponent();

    BlockSelection.ItemsSource = new List<BlockListItem> {
        new BlockListItem("BlockA", typeof(BlockA)),
        new BlockListItem("BlockB", typeof(BlockB)),
        // BlockListItem is a simple class containing just "Name" and "BlockType" as read-only auto properties.
    };
}

private static void OnBlockChange(DependencyObject conditionPresenter, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs) {
    var control = (BlockPresenter)conditionPresenter;
    var newBlock = (IBlock)eventArgs.NewValue;
    control.ContentContainer.Content = newBlock?.GetControl();
    control.BlockSelection.SelectedValue = eventArgs.NewValue?.GetType();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BlockProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Block", typeof(IBlock), typeof(BlockPresenter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnBlockChange));
public IBlock Block {
    get => (IBlock)GetValue(BlockProperty);
    set => SetValue(BlockProperty, value);
}

private void BlockSelection_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    Block = (IBlock)Activator.CreateInstance(BlockSelection.SelectedValue);
}
```

**DefaultModelControl.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid.ColumnDefitions>

    <Label Content="Main Block:" Grid.Row="0" />
    <logic:BlockPresenter Block="{Binding MainBlock}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

    <Label Content="Subblock:" Grid.Row="1" />
    <logic:BlockPresenter Block="{Binding SubBlock}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

When the main or sub block types are changed for the default model, the value inside the model (MainBlock or SubBlock properties) are not updated to reflect the newly selected block.

---

I know one solution could be to raise a custom event (e.g. BlockChanged) from the BlockPresenter when a new value is set, passing this value as event args and then capturing this event in the DefaultModelControl.xaml.cs file and setting the property to the new reference.

I was wondering if there is another way of doing this without the listeners though, since it's annoying to have to create them for each block presenter I want.

Am I going about this wrong? Would love to hear peoples constructive thoughts on this. Thanks :)

Comment: Add `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` to the FrameworkPropertyMetadata on registration of the Block dependency property.

Comment: I don't know what the selectionchanged event does. I got a bit confused by the description, but you're not binding selectedvalue on that combo. SelectedValue="{Binding  whatever}